# CSS :hover doesn't work (On desktop)

Tags: html, css, hover

i have a problem with the pseudo element :hover.

With Firefox and Firefox Developer edition:
 - :hover has no effects.
 - Work only when i click on the element.

With Safari:
 - Simply has no effects.

```css
[class*='col-'] > table, [class*='col-'] > div {
    width: 100%;
}

[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    width: 8.33%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.col-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
}
.col-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
}
.col-3 {
    width: 24.99%;
}
.col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
}
.col-5 {
    width: 41.668%;
}
.col-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
.col-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
}
.col-8 {
    width: 66.664%;
}
.col-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
}
.col-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
}
.col-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
}
.col-12 {
    width: 100%;
}
.col-r {
    float: right;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.lessons-blue p, .lessons-blue i {
    color: #6082bb;
    background-color: #6082bb;
}

.lessons-yellow p, .lessons-yellow i {
    color: #b3b300;
    background-color: #b3b300;
}

.lessons-orange p, .lessons-orange i {
    color: #cf6600;
    background-color: #cf6600;
}

.lessons-brown p, .lessons-brown i {
    color: #994d00;
    background-color: #994d00;
}

.lessons-green p, .lessons-green i {
    color: #00aa00;
    background-color: #00aa00;
}

.lessons-purple p, .lessons-purple i {
    color: #7700aa;
    background-color: #7700aa;
}

.lessons-red p, .lessons-red i{
    color: #b2222a;
    background-color: #b2222a;
}

[class*='lessons-'] {
    height: 6em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

[class*='lessons-'] a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 90;
}

[class*='lessons-'] p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-top: 50%;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: white;
    transition: padding .5s linear;
}

[class*='lessons-'] i {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 3em;
    transform: translatey(125%);
}

[class*='lessons-'] a:hover > p{
    padding-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 lessons-orange">
    <a href="#front">
      <i class="devicon-html5-plain"></i>
      <i class="devicon-css3-plain"></i>
      <p>Frontend</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 lessons-blue">
    <a href="#php">
      <i class="devicon-php-plain"></i>
      <p>PHP</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 lessons-red">
    <a href="#rbpy">
      <i class="devicon-python-plain"></i>
      <i class="devicon-ruby-plain"></i>
      <p>Ruby / Python</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 lessons-yellow">
    <a href="#javascript">
      <i class="devicon-javascript-plain"></i>
      <i class="devicon-nodejs-plain"></i>
      <p>Javascript</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 lessons-green">
    <a href="#services">
      <i class="devicon-mongodb-plain"></i>
      <i class="devicon-mysql-plain"></i>
      <i class="devicon-git-plain"></i>
      <i class="devicon-ssh-plain"></i>
      <i class="devicon-nginx-plain"></i>
      <p>Services</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 lessons-purple">
    <a href="#systems">
      <i class="devicon-linux-plain"></i>
      <i class="devicon-apple-plain"></i>
      <i class="devicon-windows8-plain"></i>
      <p>Systems</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 lessons-brown">
    <a href="#cfamily">
      <i class="devicon-c-plain"></i>
      <i class="devicon-cplusplus-plain"></i>
      <i class="devicon-csharp-plain"></i>
      <p>C Family</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help in advance !

Comment: Case-sensitivity. `translatey` doesn't exist - it's `translateY`.

Comment: I have tested on another machine, the problem come from hover system problem with my mouse. OSX and R.A.T mouses issues.

Comment: Thanks, i correct this straight away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They work for me on safari. Is it perhaps the machine you are running?

Comment: Yes, thanks ! its an MacOS with R.A.T mouses driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `Transition` property in css3?

```
 <style type="text/css">
.testing1{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #D92A2D;
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s; /*Safari 3.0 to 6*/
    transition: height 1s;
}
.testing1 p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    margin-top: auto;
}
.testing1:hover{
    height: 75px;
}
 </style>
```

And the div

```
 <div class="testing1">
     <p>RED</p>
 </div>
```

Of course this can be applied to any element, and any hover state.

Here's a handy bit about it as well, and if you add in the `-webkit` and `-moz` specific calls, you can make the same effect in all.

[W3 Schools on Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)